# CORS allowed-origin restrictions aren’t causing the server to reject requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors

I am using Spring Boot v1.5.1, and it seems my restriction on CORS origin is not working.

My application.properties file has the following line ([ref1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) [ref2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)).

```
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=http://mydomain.io
```

My REST controller looks like the following.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/car")
public class CarCtrl {
  @Autowired
  private CarService carService;

  @GetMapping
  public Car get() {
    return carService.getLatest();
  }
}
```

However, when I open up a browser and type in `http://localhost:8080/api/car` I am still able to access the REST endpoint.

I also tried to change my annotation as follows, but that does not work.

```
@CrossOrigin("${endpoints.cors.allowed-origins}")
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Note that I am not using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163672/cors-issue-with-spring-boot). Do I really need to extends this class to explicitly control origin? I figured that the `@CrossOrigin` annotation in addition to the properties file setting would be able to control the allowed origins (as opposed to having to do so programmatically).

Comment: Cors is applied when performing ajax requests. It doesn't block the browser from directly accessing API url. `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is used when you want to apply global Cors policy, `@CrossOrigin` should be enough for single resource. Why do you think it doesn't work? How did you check it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However, when I open up a browser and type in http://localhost:8080/api/car I am still able to access the REST endpoint.

CORS allowed-origins settings don’t cause servers to block requests.

And because the server isn’t blocking the request, that doesn’t prevent you from opening the URL directly in a browser.

The same-origin policy is what imposes cross-origin restrictions, and the  same-origin policy is only applied to frontend JavaScript in web applications running in a web browser, and using XHR or Fetch or jQuery `$.ajax(…)` or whatever to make cross-origin requests.

So CORS isn’t a way to cause servers to block requests. And so it also isn’t a way to prevent users from being able to directly navigate to a URL, and isn’t a way to prevent any non-web-application tools like `curl` or Postman or whatever from accessing the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly specifying the domain as string in @CrossOrigin("http://mydomain.io") will work. I dont' think this will work @CrossOrigin("${endpoints.cors.allowed-origins}").

Comment: So if I don't set the value in the annotation, will setting the value in the application.properties file apply to all my rest controllers? e.g. with `endpoints.cors.allowed-origins`?

Comment: I am not sure but I think that enables CORS globally, and you don't have to specify @CrossOrigin in your REST controller.

Answer (score 1):

As for me I am adding s CrossRef Filter on my apps.

```
 package com.alexfrndz.filter;

 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
 import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

 import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import java.io.IOException;


 @Component
 public class SimpleCORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

/**
 * The Logger for this class.
 */
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");
    //response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);


  }

}
```