# CORS with Spring Boot - restrict GET requests to certain domains

Tags: spring-boot, get

I am using Spring Boot and would like to restrict HTTP GET requests only from certain domains. For example, I would like to accept requests only from a list of predefined domains (e.g. https://www.frontend.com, https://www.test-frontend.com). How could I implement such a functionality?

I expected to face CORS issues, but theses do not apply for GET requests. Any ideas?

Comment: You can’t use CORS configuration to block requests from non-browser clients. See the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708660/cors-allowed-origin-restrictions-aren-t-causing-the-server-to-reject-requests-c/42708766#42708766 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432743/will-cors-policy-prevent-resource-access-from-non-browser-requests/43432787#43432787

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("https://www.frontend.com", "https://www.test-frontend.com")
            .allowedMethods("GET");
    }
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

Answer (score 1):

First `.allowedMethods` use for allow methods so if you don't want to allow `"GET"` then put all others methods but do not put GET method, like below:

```
.allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH")
```

and second you can not `CORS` by `non-webapp` clients like curl or Postman, any non web app client.

Comment: I had a similar configuration. I was using Postman, that was the problem.