# Laravel api block browser/postman access

Tags: php, laravel, rest, postman

I just finished `api` on `laravel` , it work perfectly on `front-end` but I want to block `api` to access via browser or postman or etc, I just want to `POST` and `GET` from my front.

for example, if someone run post request in browser:

[image]

And if run get request in browser (auth need):

[image]

Also if someone run this url `api.mywebsite.com`, see Laravel intro page, and I don't want to show to user, how can I prevent this?

And last thing, if user runs `post` or `get` request in postman, it works, and I only want it to work with my domain. I am using [this](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) CORS middleware.

1. How to prevent user access to get/post request via browser/postman?
2. How to limit api just on my domain name?

Comment: What I will do with this is, add a middleware, which will test the request type. if the request is not my planned request then it will redirect to some page like page404

Comment: Use Reverse proxying, send the request back to your frontend server and route the request from webserver to your API server

Comment: @sheelpriy any example or doc?

Comment: CORS is not a mechanism for causing servers to block requests. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708766/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069745/441757. CORS is a way to prevent browsers from blocking access to responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove `Laravel` welcome page:

Go to

`route/web.php`, comment this line:

```
return view('welcome');
```

Or replace with:

```
return abort(404);
```

Or you can remove with own route, it return same `404`

---

For remove route `login`, you need to go to:

```
app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php
```

Find and replace `redirectTo` function with:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return abort('404');
    }
}
```

Or really `redirect` to your `login` page, or etc.

---

And go to `config/cors.php` and replace yours with this:

```
'allowed_origins' => ['http://yourwebsite.com'],
```

And no need to worry about `postman` but if you want to avoid people do a direct request to your `api` you need to use `api_token`

---

Oh I forgot your another question, after all, you should not see any of these errors on your browser, except you forget to set these on `.env`:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```