# CORS / CORB error in Eclipse on same domain (Extjs / java Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, extjs

I'm facing a CORS problem in Eclipse and simply can't get it resolved.

I tried the correspondig tomcat approaches from this site: http://docs.motechproject.org/en/latest/deployment/CORS_Headers.html#tomcat-web-server-config but without success.

I'm using Java IDE for Web Developers and Google Chrome Version 103 on Windows Server 2022 and Windows 10 Professional.
I'm developing with Spring Boot and Extjs 7 GPL

Here my web.xml:

```html
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>localhost:1841</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,Accept,Authorization,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>localhost:1841</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And here the corresponding extjs Store:

```js
Ext.define('MyBankingApp.store.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    xtype: 'userStore',
    id:'userStoreID',
    requires: [
        'MyBankingApp.model.User'
    ],
    
    autoLoad: false,
    model: 'MyBankingApp.model.User',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyBankingApp/user', 
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'useDefaultXhrHeader': false,
            'cors': true,
            'withCredentials': true
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }   
    }
});
```

Here the result in Chrome with HTTP response code 403 after attempting to send:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/MyBankingApp/user?_dc=1657378909025&page=1&start=0&limit=25' from origin 'http://localhost:1841' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> ext-all-debug.js?_dc=1657378899641:28132
> GET http://localhost:8080/MyBankingApp/user?_dc=1657378909025&page=1&start=0&limit=25 net::ERR_FAILED

As you can see above, the problem is not the domain (both localhost), but the different port: 1841 (sencha app watch) and 8080 Eclipse Tomcat.

But after linking the web.xml to Eclipse and preparing it as you could see, this should run - but seemingly it doesn't...

Therefore I bid you kindly for any hint in order to resolve this problem - there simply must be a way to achieve my goal in Eclipse.

**UPDATE:**
I tried the approach to alter the allowed origins in web.xml: localhost / localhost:1841 / *, but unfortunately the same error as explained above

**UPDATE2:**
One kind of workaround should be, that I run both the sencha and the spring boot part on the same server, i.e. port.
For the moment this should be enough.

I bid you all kindly to give me some approach, how I could get this done, as I after some research don't really have an idea how to start in order to use 1 server only.
Thank you in advance

Comment: please do not post images of code as it is against the rules https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question please read the rules before posting on stack overflow

Comment: I will pay more attention

Comment: Edit your question to remove the image and include the code instead well formatted. Voted to close

Comment: I hope it's better now

Comment: I would definitely recommend hosting your front-end on the same application as your back-end. There really isn't a reason why you should seperate them. As for your CorsFilter you need to add the scheme as well `http://localhost:1841` and add a wildcard like `"/*"` to the URL-pattern. Otherwise tomcat wont match any requests to the filter

Comment: It seems like I could resolve my CORS issue by following the _second approach_ of **Grinish Nepal's** answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163672/cors-issue-with-spring-boot?rq=1. So basically I got what I want - for the moment. But yes @DGK you are totally right: the main goal of course is to let both parts run on 1 server only. This is the problem I'm facing at the moment ...

Comment: Ah, and furthermore: I could successfully integrate _dreamfactory_ now, so I can finally get the data for the Extjs part independently